# Adjust GridView (Android)

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a problem with grid view layout on Android. I can't find solution to eliminate extra space in grid view.I mention the code fro gridview as below :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
android:clipChildren="true"
android:columnWidth="100dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:padding="0dp"
android:scrollingCache="true"
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />
```

now my application's grid view look like this
[image]

As shown there is extra space which i want to remove it and it can look like this:-

[image]

So please provide me solution..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the value for `android:columnWidth` attribute for all layout types [hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi etc.] supported by your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

`android:listSelector="@null"`

to eliminate extera space
and try this , for 3 column cell:

`android:numColumn = "3"`